# Retrieving the items from Knapsack [one dimensional array implementation]

Tags: algorithm

This algorithm works fine [Are these 2 knapsack algorithms the same? (Do they always output the same thing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683155/are-these-2-knapsack-algorithms-the-same-do-they-always-output-the-same-thing)

How do we retrieve the items that were selected in the process?

This is the algorithm from the previous post

```
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    if (C-w[j] < 0) continue;
    for (int i = C-w[j]; i >= 0; --i) { //loop backwards to prevent double counting
        dp[i + w[j]] = max(dp[i + w[j]], dp[i] + v[j]); //looping fwd is for the unbounded problem
    }
}
printf( "max value without double counting (loop backwards) %d\n", dp[C]);
```

This is an example:

```
For C = 9 and N = 3

Values and Weights: 
5 4
6 5
3 2
```

The Knapsack array is the following:

```
0 0 3 3 5 6 8 9 9 11
```

Which gives the optimal value = 11 by choosing item 1 and item 2

How to retrieve the selected items? or How to know which items did we select?
[Item 1 and Item 2]

Adding another example:

```
weight: 16 19 23 28
value: 2 3 4 5
C = 7
```

Iteration 1

```
0 16 16 16 16 16 16
```

Iteration 2

```
0 16 19 19 35 35 35
```

Iteration 3

```
0 16 19 23 35 39 42
```

Iteration 4

```
0 16 19 28 35 39 44
```

The optimal value = 44 with items 1 and 4

Comment: Any summary of what they do? Also, anything you'd want to, you know, ask?

Comment: Along with the DP array, keep an array that for every value tells you the optimal `j` that you need to choose.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace your max call by a check whether the just found solution is better than any previously seen. If so, store it away for later reference.

Comment: is it possible to provide an example?